# Non-vanishing matrix elements in QFT after discretization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, solid-state-physics, discrete, lattice-model

In QFT, introducing the lattice size $L$ implies that the momentum of plane wave solutions is discretized as
$$\vec{p}_\vec{n} = \dfrac{2\pi}{L}\vec{n}\quad,\qquad \vec{n}\in\mathbb{Z}^D$$
I would like to calculate matrix elements of the interacting Hamiltonian between certain states of the free theory Fock space. For example, I want to study the elastic scattering
$$\vec{p}_1,\vec{p}_2\rightarrow \vec{p}_1^{\,\prime},\vec{p}_2^{\,\prime}$$
In the CMS, we simply have $\vec{p}_1 = -\vec{p}_2$.
No matter what the precise form of the dispersion relation is, the conservation of energy and momentum imply that the two outgoing particles have momenta $\vec{p}_1^{\,\prime} = -\vec{p}_2^{\,\prime}$, where $|\vec{p}_1^{\,\prime}|=|\vec{p}_1^{\,\prime}|=|\vec{p}_1|$. In other words, they live on the opposite sides of the sphere of radius $|\vec{p}_1|$ in the momentum space.

Here comes my question: After discretization, this sphere will only intersect the $D$-dimensional lattice at the points lying on coordinate axes. In other cases, we either have to sacrifice the fact that we stay on the lattice (we need states with irrational components of momenta) or the conservation of energy (for all other momenta we have to go off the sphere).

So how should this all work in practice? Is energy conserved approximately? Assume, I have introduced the lattice size $L$ and the momentum cutoff $p_{max}=\dfrac{2\pi}{L}\Lambda$. This way, I end up with finite-size-matrix quantum mechanics. In such a setting, for which states will the matrix element
$$\langle?|\hat{H}|\hat{a}^\dagger_{\vec{p}_1}\hat{a}^\dagger_{\vec{p}_2}|\operatorname{vac}\rangle$$
be non-vanishing? I'm not interested in the case of $k$ being extremely large, so $\vec{p}_1 = \dfrac{2\pi}{L}\vec{n}_1$ where $\vec{n}_1$ is relatively close to zero.